# Using invoke without a control

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events

I have a Component (System.ComponentModel.Component)

This component receives an event from another Thread. Normally I would use this pattern to execute this code in the GUI thread

```
private void handle_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var control = this.Button1;
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
        control.Invoke(() => DoSomething());
    else
        DoSomeThing();
}
```

However, in this special case I don't have a control. How do I do this?

Comment: You can't do this directly from a Component.  You will need a reference to a Control or better yet a SychronizationContext to be able to Invoke a call on the GUI thread.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Copy SynchronizationContext.Current in your constructor.  Use its Post() method later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the current [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the background thread, you can ask it to [Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (begininvoke) or [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (invoke) the code required on the foreground thread.

Here's a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program to demonstrate:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var fm = new Form())
    {
        var btn = new Button();
        fm.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += HandleClick;

        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Dump("Main thread");
        fm.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public static void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        () => BackgroundMethod(synchronizationContext)));
    thread.Start();
}

public static void BackgroundMethod(SynchronizationContext context)
{
    context.Post(state =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Dump("Invoked thread");
    }, null);
}
```

Comment: Looks promissing, I will try that

Answer (score -2):

Use Dispatcher to run your code in GUI thread...hope am getting your problem right.

```
private void handle_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Button1.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)() => {
            DoSomething();
   });
}
```

Please check for the syntax errors :|

Comment: But the OP noted that there's no GUI.

Comment: I feel, if there is a button (Button1) then definitely there is a GUI and its dispatcher will definitely link me to its respective GUI thread...