# How to invoke from UI thread (C# .NET 2)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates, invoke

Usually we invoke on UI thread that way :

`myControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { Foo(); });`

Are they any way to do it without any control instance ? I mean something like this :

`System.Windows.Forms.Thread.Invoke(...);`

---

**Solution**
Solution given by dcastro, using [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx). Here is a really simple example in a form :

```
public partial class FrmFoo : Form
{
    SynchronizationContext uiThread;

    public void FrmFoo()
    {
        // Needs to assign it from somewhere in the UI thread (in constructor for example)
        uiThread = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    void AsyncBar()
    {
        uiThread.Send(delegate(object state)
        {
            // UI Cross-Thread dangerous manips allowed here
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681700/using-invoke-without-a-control

Comment: This really is the old way of doing things. Telling people the .NET version you are using will help bring more modern answers... along with a use case.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead .NET 2 compatibility is a technical constraint, I have no choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx) (available since .NET 2.0)

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate, state);
```

You should grab a reference to the context from your UI thread, and make it accessible to your other threads, which can then use it to execute code on the UI thread.

This is equivalent to `BeginInvoke`.
For a `Invoke` equivalent, use the `Send` method instead.

Comment: This solution will not work when called from a worker thread.

Comment: @Gusdor It won't but the `Current` instance can be catched from the right thread and the "WindowsForms(..)" protects to catch an other context. I update my post with solution example

Comment: @56ka Absolutely! If the answer would make that clear, I would not have felt inclined to comment upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SynchronizationContext` and it's `Post` method

```
var sCon=SynchronizationContext.Current;
        sCon.Post(new SendOrPostCallback((o) => {
            //do your stuffs
        }), null);
```

> SynchronizationContext is just an abstraction, one that represents a
>   particular environment you want to do some work in.  As an example of
>   such an environment, Windows Forms apps have a UI thread (while it’s
>   possible for there to be multiple, for the purposes of this discussion
>   it doesn’t matter), which is where any work that needs to use UI
>   controls needs to happen.  For cases where you’re running code on a
>   ThreadPool thread and you need to marshal work back to the UI so that
>   this work can muck with UI controls, Windows Forms provides the
>   Control.BeginInvoke method.  You give a delegate to a Control’s
>   BeginInvoke method, and that delegate will be invoked back on the
>   thread with which that control is associated.

Comment: From msdn: `Gets the synchronization context for the current thread.` When called from a worker thread, this solution will not work - `SynchronizationContext.Current` will return `null` or worse, the default context.

Comment: This is the first step, thank you